# Laravel - jQuery not working while right path?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

This question is asked many times before but i can't find the answer that solves my question. I made a fresh Laravel 6 project and trying to use JS. You can load your js files in the layout.blade like this (Unless they changed it in Laravel 6)

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js') !!}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/main.js') !!}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{!! asset('js/app.js') !!}"></script>
```

But is does not seem to work for me.
My javascript files are in `public/js/...` and the above scripts are at the bottom of my blade file

**Blade file**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-white shadow-sm">
            <div class="container">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url('/') }}">
                    {{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="{{ __('Toggle navigation') }}">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                    <!-- Left Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                    </ul>

                    <!-- Right Side Of Navbar -->
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                        <!-- Authentication Links -->
                        @guest
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('login') }}">{{ __('Login') }}</a>
                            </li>
                            @if (Route::has('register'))
                                <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('register') }}">{{ __('Register') }}</a>
                                </li>
                            @endif
                        @else
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a id="navbarDropdown" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" v-pre>
                                    {{ Auth::user()->name }} <span class="caret"></span>
                                </a>

                                <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('logout') }}"
                                       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                     document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                        {{ __('Logout') }}
                                    </a>

                                    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                                        @csrf
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                        @endguest
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="py-4">
            @yield('content')
        </main>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/main.js') }}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my `main.js` i've put a simple alert to check if the code is working but it does not show and does not give me errors in the console. What is causing this?

**Main.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    alert("wow");


});
```

Comment: The asset function links to the assets present in public folder not resources folder. So you should place your js files in your public/js path

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The files are in de public/js folder but still don't work.

Comment: Check your console from developer tools. It will show you the path it's actually trying to fetch file from. If you can show that msg it will be helpful

Comment: The console unfortunately does not give me any feedback

Comment: Are you sure you are in same route to which the blade file is viewed? Check source and see if actually these tags are present in source code from browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/mix) and *secure_asset* instead of *asset*.

Edit your webpack.mix.js file like that:

```
mix.scripts([
    'resources/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js',
    'resources/js/main.js',
    'resources/js/app.js'
], 'public/js/scripts.js');
```

Then run this command:

```
npm run dev
```

And put this in your blade file:

```
<script src="{{ secure_asset('js/scripts.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: It still does not work. it compiles successfully but no feedback whatsoever

Comment: It's completely empty

Answer (score 0):

Are you using webpack?
If yes you have to mix js into public directory:
Add this line to your main.js on the top:
`require('./jquery-3.4.1.min');`
and this to webpack.mix.js
`mix.js('resources/js/main.js', 'public/js');`
then run `npm run development`

Add only main.js to blade file or mix your JS files separately from each other without require.